# Confusion with sortUsingSelector

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I was having some confusion when the book started talking about alphabetizing elements in the array using the `sort` and `compareNames:` method. How is the argument for `compareNames` obtained when the method `sort` is called? And how do the elements actually get alphabetize when all that's returned is a type of `NSComparisonResult`?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AddressCard : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name, *email;

-(NSComparisonResult) compareNames: (id) element;

@end

@implementation AddressCard 
@synthesize name, email;

-(NSComparisonResult) compareNames:(id)element {
    return [name compare: [element name]];
}
@end
```

---

```
#import "AddressCard.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AddressBook : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *bookName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *book;

-(void) addCard: (AddressCard *) myCard;
-(void) sort;

@end

@implementation AddressBook
@synthesize book, bookName;

-(void) sort {
    [book sortUsingSelector: @selector(compareNames:)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NSComparisonResult` is just one of `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame`, `NSOrderedDescending`.

The method `compareNames` is responsible of the true comparison. In this case, since you are comparing strings, the method just rely on already-implemented `compare` method of `NSString`. The result gives information about the comparison between two strings according to the alphabetical order.

Method `sortUsingSelector` of `NSMutableArray` is a useful method to sort custom types of data (you can appreciate better if you try to sort custom objects according to custom criteria). It accepts a selector, which means that every time it needs to compare two object, the method specified by the selector is called.

For what I remember you are not allowed to know the method `sortUsingSelector` internally uses (quick sort / heap sort / bubble sort...), what you need to know is that object are ordered using the criteria specified by the implementation of the method you pass with the selector.

Answer (score 1):

The `compareNames:` method is repeatedly called by the sorting method (`sortUsingSelector:`) for every pair of elements it needs to compare; it supplies the arguments. Exactly which pairs of elements it compares to sort the array depends on the sorting algorithm. The Apple docs do not mention which method is used but [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is a fairly common one. If you look at the Wikipedia page you should probably be able to see how by repeatedly comparing pairs of items you can end up with the complete array sorted.